# Trying To Add A User And Render New Page With JS and Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a form that allows users to enter data.
[image]

When the user clicks "Add User", the user is created in the database but the form stays populated on this page. It does not render the next page as I expect. The `addUser` handlebars page that this form uses contains the following portion for adding the user.

```
<input id="addUser" type="submit" name="add" value="Add User" onclick="addRow()" />
```

The `addRow()` function is in my script.js file and contains the following code.

```
function addRow(){

    var form = document.getElementById("userForm");
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
          // Add the form data to the ajax request
          var queryString = "";

          var fname = form.fname.value;
          var lname = form.lname.value;
          var email = form.email.value;
          var company = form.company.value;
          var password = form.password.value;

          queryString += "fname=" + fname + "&";
          queryString += "lname=" + lname + "&";
          queryString += "email=" + email + "&";
          queryString += "company=" + company + "&";
          queryString += "password=" + password;

          //window.location.href = "/insert-user?" + queryString;

          req.open('GET', '/insert-user?' + queryString, true);

          //console.log('-->', result.response.status);

          //req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          req.addEventListener('load', function(){
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){

            }
          else{
                console.log("Error in network request: " + req.statusText);
          }});

          req.send();
          event.preventDefault();
          //return false;
}
```

The server-side code that is executed for inserting the user is here:

```
app.get('/insert-user',function(req,res){
  var context = {};
  pool.query("INSERT INTO user (`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`,`timestamp`,`company`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)", 
  [req.body.fname, req.body.lname, req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.company], 
  function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    res.render('adminDash',context);
    console.log("Success");
  });
});
```

My debug statement of "Success" prints but I am not getting "adminDash" to render. I have checked the terminal and the console for any server errors and they do not exist. This makes sense since the data IS being inserted into the table but I cannot figure out why `adminDash` is not rendering. I'm guessing it must be something on the client side (potentially in addRow())? Does anyone have any tips for troubleshooting this issue so I can isolate the problem further?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not doing anything with the response from the `XMLHttpRequest`.

I won't lie: I don't know the "right" way to do this as I'm just learning node/handlebars myself, but this will work:

```
if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){
    document.write(req.response); // write the response to the page
}
```

Not knowing anything about the `adminDash` file, I can't tell you if it will matter that the `context` object you're passing in the render call is apparently empty.